# How can I access list that is located at the root site from a subsite?

Tags: 2010, list

How can I access list that is located at the root site from a sub site?

Comment: Can you explain how you need to access it?  I.e. in code, via rollup, OOB webpart, etc..

Comment: type its url in the browser.

Comment: I wanted to have a list on the root that several subsites could use the data in that root list as look up values in  subsite specific lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C#, dead simple:

```
SPWeb rootWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPList targetList = rootWeb.Lists["MyTargetListName"];
```

Comment: Thank you - but I need an out of the box solution or a solutions that uses designer.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons (and technical ones as well) SharePoint does not support using lists outside of the current site as a lookup list.

You could do one of the following:

1) Create a template of the main list with data and use that to replicate the list everywhere you need it

2) Use an InfoPath form.  The lookup would happen within the InfoPath form, not in the SharePoint column itself.  InfoPath can use list data from other SharePoint sites in its data connections.