# Create a lookup column in a list to reference a column in a list on another site (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: list, lookup-column

Is this possible with an OOB solution: 
I have list A on Site A and List B on Site B (site B is NOT a subsite of site A). There is a column in list A on Site A that I need to use in list B on site B. This reuse would reduce redundancy of data and also more importantly should eliminate duplicate maintenance when there are updates to the column data.

The company uses SharePoint 2007 and I do have SharePoint Designer as well and could possibly utilize this if a solution exists...

Thanks,
Maria

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access list that is located at the root site from a subsite?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46012/how-can-i-access-list-that-is-located-at-the-root-site-from-a-subsite)

Comment: I don't think it is - the Q. specifically says that B is not a sub-site of A.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the two sites in question are in two different site collections, then it is not possible OOB. But if both of them are in same site collection, then using lookups can solve your problem.